# Combining lists which has corresponding values

Tags: python

I am new to python, so in need of help. I am having a three lists in which the values correspond to each other. As in an excel like below

```
ID           Name         Height 
1             u              5
2             s              7
3             d              9
4             u              7
5             k              7
6             z              5
```

and so on.

Now from this table I want to combine the ID which are having same height.
names as in not so important.. How do I do that using python.

Comment: Help us help you - Please share the code you have so far, and the result you're trying to get.

Answer (score 0):

To get better answers, check out the formatting tools to make things easier to read.

```
ID Name Height 
1  u    5 
2  s    7
3  d    9
...
```

The easiest way to do what you're looking for would be to check out 'groupby' from the 'itertools' package.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html

First, assuming all lists are of equal length, put them together into a merged list.

```
newList = [(a,b,c) for a,b,c in zip(list1, list2, list3)]
```

newList would look something like this:

```
[(1,u,5),(2,s,7),(3,d,9),(4,u,7),...]
```

Now you can use groupby to group everything by height.

```
from itertools import groupby

data = sorted(newlist, key=lambda x: x[2])  # Sort "newlist" by height values
for k,g in groupby(data, lambda x: x[2])
    # k is now the height value
    group = list(g)  # group will now have all of the matching list elements with the same height
    ids = [x[1] for x in group]  # This would be the list of ids with the height from k...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this with pandas module from python and using groupby function. see below example.

```
import pandas as pd

id1 = [1203,1204,1205,1206,1207,1208]    #list of id's
name = ['john','mike','henry','cart','rob','sam']    #list of names
height = [5,4,5,7,2,4]    #list of heights

df = pd.DataFrame({'id':id1, 'name':name, 'height':height})    #creating a dataframe from id, name and height lists

df2 = df.groupby('height').apply(lambda x: x['id'].unique())    #grouping the id's having same height

print(df2)
```

Output:

```
height
2          [1207]
4    [1204, 1208]
5    [1203, 1205]
7          [1206]
dtype: object
```

Also if you not bothered about the names column you can simply do that using defaultdict with only id and height column. see below example.

```
from collections import defaultdict

id1 = [1203,1204,1205,1206,1207,1208]  #list of id's
height = [5,4,5,7,2,4]  #list of heights

data = dict(zip(id1,height))  #creating a normal dictionary with id's and height

result = defaultdict()  #creating a default dictionary

for key,value in data.items():
    if value in result.keys():
        result[value].append(key)
    else:
        result[value] = [key]

print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, welcome to StackOverflow!

I believe what you're trying to ask is a method to extract the contents of an Excel spreadsheet and use that content to find and combine the ID numbers which have the same height.

To do this, you'll need a way to read an Excel spreadsheet in Python.
You can do this in two methods:

1. Convert the spreadsheet to a CSV (comma-separated-values) file which can be easily used by Python using the **csv** module.
2. Use an external library that helps you read from and write to Excel spreadsheets directly, like **xlrd** and **xlwt**. As the name suggests, **xlrd** is a module that lets you read data from the Excel spreadsheet and **xlwt** lets you write to the Excel spreadsheet.

Assuming that you only need to read data from the spreadsheet, I'll share my method which would use the xlrd module.

First, install the xlrd module by using the command:

```
pip install xlrd
```

Then, in your Python program, import the xlrd module and open the spreadsheet like so:

```
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('spreadsheet_file.xls')
```

If you have a large file, use the ondemand option along with the above statement, like this:

```
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('spreadsheet_file.xls', on_demand = True)
```

Assuming that the spreadsheet is the first in the Excel workbook, open it like so:

```
worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
```

This will open the first spreadsheet in the Excel workbook.

Now, to access data from the spreadsheet, you'll need to do this:

```
value = worksheet.cell(row_index, column_index).value
```

So, in theory, your solution would be roughly similar to this:

```
import xlrd

book = xlrd.open_workbook('your_spreadsheet_file.xls')
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
list_values = list()

row_ind = 0
while sheet.cell(row_ind, 0).value != xlrd.empty_cell.value:
    list_values.append((
      sheet.cell(row_ind, 0).value,
      sheet.cell(row_ind, 1).value,
      sheet.cell(row_ind, 2).value))
    row_ind += 1
```

Now you'll have a list of tuples that can be used to do whatever you like.
After this, if you do want to group them by height, referring to user1209675's answer should do well.